# How to filter records by words in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to get results from SQL table.
In my application I used fulltext search.
I want to get:

for example If user enter word like "**Great Events**". Then result should be comes as below sequence.

1. first result related to whole word "**Great Events**" and then
2. "Great" related result then
3. "Events" related result.

The first results should be all updates with the entire search term "**Great Events**".

Only after you show these results, then display updates with term "**Great Events**",   "Greater Events" etc.
Basically words that contain the terms "Great Events".

Then show results from updates that have both words "Great" and "Events", and its variations.
Finally, show results from updates that have one of the two words...

My table likes: 
Columns 
**UserUpdates**

---

**UpdateID - int 

UserID  - int 

MsgText - nvarchar(500) 

CreatedOn -  datetime**

How to do using SQL script.. ?

Comment: Do you want this to be dynamic for the number of words in the search expression, too? Do you allow wildcards?

Comment: yes. When user enter into search textbox then I get result as per the entire text.....! allow wildcards means?

Comment: Allowing wildcards means that you allow your users to search for example for "Great Event*", where * can be replaced by anything to end the word.

Comment: @Tomas no there is not used wildcard in search box..

Comment: Column:MsgText contains messages that I want to search from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a fulltext catalog and add a fulltext index on your table to solve this.

Do do this , you might create a simple parser in c# to take the search terms and create a search keyword; turning the search for "great events" to something like :

'"great events" OR (Great AND Events)'

You can than create a query like this, based on that search keyword:

SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE ([YourFullTextIndexTable], *, '"great events" OR (Great AND Events)' , 2057,0)
ORDER BY RANK DESC

The above is for british english (2057) and the default stoplist (0).

This would return records with "Great Events" as a phrase first followed by records with Great and Events in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I already created full text.. can we create query dynamic like you said 'Great And Events' If user search 'Abc def ghi' like this then we have to split words and append to query..